# Aggregating a column in a dataset based on value in another column in the same dataset in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to aggregate a part of a dataset to be used as an expression.
I have a dataset called Weekly with some columns of with 1 is SalesSelling and another is TimeGroup, Sales as sales data values while Timegroup has String datavalues such as LW = Last Week, TW = This Week, LY= Last year etc
I want to Aggregate the Sales column when the TimeGroup Column Has the LW values using an expression.
I have tried:

```
=Switch(Fields!SalesSelling.Value "LW", Sum(Fields!SalesSelling.Value))
=IIF(Fields!TimeGroup.Value = "LW",Sum(Fields!SalesSelling.Value),0)
```

However they don't work does anyone know how to accomplish this. my intension is to calculate percentage variance for last week ant this week however I need summations first.

Answer (score 0):

I would put the IIf inside the Sum, e.g.

`=Sum(IIF(Fields!TimeGroup.Value = "LW",Fields!SalesSelling.Value,0))`

Comment: After searching I think what I needed was how to use the Lookup function, however that still has not worked. However I do think the above answer could be useful in some cases.